# Storage engine for high volume of selects

Tags: mysql, performance, storage-engines

## Background

I am creating an API utilizing the Bible where I would like to be able to eliminate as much as the database bottleneck as possible.  My data is fairly de-normalised to eliminate most unnecessary joins.

## Information

**Seeing as the text of the Bible doesn't change**, I will be doing hardly any `INSERT` statements.  The only time I will insert data is when I add a new translation, which will happen periodically, but I don't care about the speed here.

**I will, however, be doing *tons* of** `SELECT` **statements.**

I do not need any transnational, ACID compliant features.  My primary concern is speed.

## The Question

What would the ideal MySql storage engine be to fit these conditions?

I am aware of the basics of each engine (my guess would that `MyISAM` is ideal), so I am looking for an answer that can be backed up with statistics or further reasoning demonstrating a deep knowledge of some of these engines.

Although using `NoSQL` may be better than a `RDBMS`, that is not the information I'm looking for.

Comment: "Chapter 8 Optimization" of the MySQL reference might be worth reading.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization.html

Comment: Since it sounds like you'll be doing full-text search, have you looked at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the bible is small in terms of file size. and as you said doesnt change.

For the best performance on reads consider Memory. This has the limitation that you cant use text / blob. But providing your data is split into  65,533 char chunks you will be fine.

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html
```

Using memory also means if power is lost / server is restarted all data is lost. so periodically writing to disk will be useful and on restart you will need to populate the table again.

You will need extra RAM to use this method over other methods though as all tables are stored in RAM

From the question in the comments.

The docs say

> To populate a MEMORY table when the MySQL server starts, you can use
>   the --init-file option. For example, you can put statements such as
>   INSERT INTO ... SELECT or LOAD DATA INFILE into this file to load the
>   table from a persistent data source. See Section 5.1.3, “Server
>   Command Options”, and Section 13.2.6, “LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax”.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html#idp82809968

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file

Again you will need to keep this file up to date with any changes. (can use a mysqldump to maintain it)

Comment: Do you know of a way to automatically re-populate if I have a MyISAM or InnoDB backup version stored?  Can MySQL manage it itself?

Answer (score 1):

Innodb with good indexes maybe even good partitions.
innodb is designed to have better performance with multible threads clients (read more clients at the same time) vs MyISAM is not build for that.

if the server is correcly configured Innodb will really blast away myisam on performance

Comment: not with Reads. innodb is acid compatible meaning IO even for reads

Comment: Please i sad a correcly configured server for innodb would blast away Myisam. Read  http://www.oracle.com/partners/en/knowledge-zone/mysql-5-5-innodb-myisam-522945.pdf the facts and undo the downvote...

Comment: i didnt downvote, and that is comparing on transactions, Something which innodb is better at. MyISAM is a more simple structure and has to do less per read than innodb

Comment: Pretty new on this website i was thinking you did the downvote.. yes indeed don't use COUNT(*) without a WHERE with indexed fields on innodb tables for example. simple structure is not always the best and innodb didn't become the default storage engine for mysql without a good reason.

Comment: InnoDB will outperform MyISAM. It's newer, and even if it's acid compliant - it doesn't mean it will spend an I/O per 1 select. Also, properly configured, InnoDB will keep the working data set in memory therefore not hitting the disk while reading.